# Extend Workflow Foundation FlowChart

Tags: workflow-foundation, flowchart

I would like to create a custom reusable workflow foundation activity based on the FlowChart activity.  All of the built in classes are sealed therefore I cannot inherit it.  These activities will be used in an application which re-hosts the workflow designer and used by non-developers. I can inherit from the NativeActivity class.  However, I need to be able to drag and drop activities into this custom activity just like the FlowChart activity.

Summary: does anyone have an example or ideas on how to implement a custom workflow activity which behaves just like the FlowChart (in the designer and at runtime) but allows me to extend the class with my own custom logic behind the scenes?

I think I may be simply looking for or reusing the same ActivityDesigner that the FlowChart uses.  Is that possible?

Comment: Exactly what behavior are you looking for? In what way will it act like a FlowChart?

Comment: I'm curious in this too, and I think the answer has something to do with implementing a custom activity and a custom activity designer class. I think the flowchart view then comes as part of the WF designer's interaction with the custom activity design class.

Comment: I'm not even sure which ActivityDesigner is used to make a FlowChart.

Comment: If I could simply inherit the FlowChart activity, that would be ideal.  I want to add custom logic to the FlowChart to track specific data related to our business. I am developing an applicaiton which would re-host the Workflow Designer.  Non-developers would be using this so I don't want to simply have FlowChart templates containing activities that have that logic in there because users could remove them.  I want them to be able to drag and drop pre-built FlowChart components then allow them to drag a few custom activities into that custom FlowChart activity (i.e. FTP Download, etc.)

Comment: The other thing I've tried is creating a custom Activity inheriting "NativeActivity".  What I thought would work would be to add the following attribute to the class; however the FlowChartDesigner class doesn't appear to be public.

[Designer(typeof(System.Activities.Core.Presentation.FlowChartDesigner))]
    public class TestActivity : NativeActivity
{...}

Answer (score 1):

rock!
I think you can use this approach:
you have some build-in sealed Code activities (flowstep, flowdecision) which you cannot alter, but you can create other designers (i.e. UI) for them. I managed to customize this way the flowdecision designer, by adding triggers to apply color effects. Further more, you can automatically assign to it the condition (by binding it to an internal flowchart variable for example) by using base ActivityDesigner class overrides.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to do this, I would probably go into Reflector and find the class that I want to modify, then copy and paste it into a project in VS. At this point, I would compile, find out what other internal/private classes it depends on, and copy those. After iterating a couple dozen times, I would have something that compiles without errors and I can start integrating it into the rest of my system.

It's not pretty, but I don't think there's any other way to extend an internal or private class.

Of course you could do this whole thing, only to find that the designer has some special case code that looks for the particular class you want to extend, such that getting the behavior you want is impossible.

Comment: It is appearing more and more that what' I'm looking for is to tell my new custom Activity (which inherits from NativeActivity just like the FlowChart activity) to use the FlowChart Designer by adding the [Designer(...)] attribute; however, it appears that the FlowChart Designer isn't public or has a public contstructor, so I can't seem to get to it.  I basically want the FlowChart designer functionality in the Workflow Designer, but custom Native Activity functionality, if that makes sense.